# Monotouch - Is it possible to use a SQL Server CE database in an iPad/iPhone project?

Tags: database, xamarin.ios, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I've started to use Sqlite in my iPad project, however I would rather to use SQL Server CE database instead.

Does anyone know whether it is possible?

If so, have you got some simple instructions on how to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible, because SQL Server CE is not available for iOS.